# Avoid special characters js or Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to avoid special character in inputs with js, on keypress or keydown. I'm trying with different ways but de character ^ or Ç always win. Please help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including input and expected results as well as a  a properly detailed problem description

Comment: If you are using Angular, you can use pattern validator for example with a regular expression.

Comment: Please do not down vote the question directly if someone is new on SO. Give your hand and time to help them. I have added a sample code and its solution here.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the special characters `onkeypress` event, you go as following.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/C1S5ltmNzLuxOdT4IbW1?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">

<script>
function myFunction(e) {
    var x = e.which || e.keyCode;//depends on browser support
    if((x >= 48 && x <= 57) || (x >= 97 && x <= 122) || (x >= 65 && x <= 91))
    {
        //your code goes here
    }else e.preventDefault();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Let us know If it was helpful.

Comment: It allows `+´ç¨Ç^  Thanks for answering.

Comment: I have no idea about the chars ç¨Ç, but the above example doesn't allow '+' and '^'. I have provided a Plunker example. Please check that.